# Extracting strings between two regular expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a txt file containing transcriptions of congressional speeches from the 19th century. This is the broad format:

```
Mr. JOHNSON. Researching congress is neat!  
Mr. JACKSON. For sure. Sometimes I think 
that I would do it for a living.  
Mr. SMITH, of Virginia. But then I realize
it's actually pretty hard!
```

I want to build a data frame that separates the chunks said by each speaker. Something like:

```
SPEAKER                   STATEMENT
Mr. JOHNSON               Researching ...
Mr. Jackson               For sure. ...
Mr. Smith, of Virginia    But then...
```

I've figured out a regex that can identify each instance of Mr. [something] or Mr. [something, of some place] (the speeches are from a time when they're unfortunately all Mr.). It's this:

```
pattern <- regex("((Mr\\.\\s[A-Z][A-Za-z1-9]+)(\\,\\sof\\s[A-Za-z1-9]+\\.|\\.)|(The\\sCHAIRMAN))", dotall = TRUE)
str_extract_all(data, pattern)
```

This returns

```
[1] Mr. JOHNSON.
[2] Mr. JACKSON.
[3] Mr. SMITH, of Virginia.
```

My issue is now: how do I extract the text *between* each of these extracted names? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
library(qdapRegex)
ex_between(data, pattern, pattern)[[1]]
```

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I know regex in python. Is it possible to use regex to substitute the speaker with nothing. So you would replace the speaker's name with an empty string and that would leave you with the remaining text?

Comment: Could you indicate how you created the variable `data` ? How the text is read into R is important to help answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally love `for` loops but this does work.  It builds off your attempt with `ex_between`, but has a special case for the last statement (since that statement isn't between two speakers).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(qdapRegex)
data <- read_file("Mr. JOHNSON. Researching congress is neat!
Mr. JACKSON. For sure. Sometimes I think that I would do it for a living.
Mr. SMITH, of Virginia. But then I realize it's actually pretty hard!")
data <- data %>% 
  str_replace_all("\\\n", " ")

pattern <- regex("((Mr\\.\\s[A-Z][A-Za-z1-9]+)(\\,\\sof\\s[A-Za-z1-9]+\\.|\\.)|(The\\sCHAIRMAN))", dotall = TRUE)
people <- str_extract_all(data, pattern)[[1]]

statements <- as.character()
for (i in seq(1, length(people))) {
  if (i <= length(people) - 1) {
    statements[i] <- ex_between(data, people[i], people[i + 1])[[1]][1]
  } else {
    statements[i] <-
      str_extract_all(data, sprintf("(?<=%s).*", people[i]))[[1]][1]
  }
}

df <- data.frame(people, statements, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

                   people                                                   statements
1            Mr. JOHNSON.                                Researching congress is neat!
2            Mr. JACKSON. For sure. Sometimes I think that I would do it for a living.
3 Mr. SMITH, of Virginia.                But then I realize it's actually pretty hard!
```